# VBA Looping Through Range to Create New Data Output where Criteria Are Met

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a set of data (sample):

```
Maturity    Price
17/11/2017  2165
15/12/2017  2165
17/11/2017  2170
15/12/2017  2170
19/01/2018  2170
```

For each price on the list, I want to create an output of this price vs every other price on the list (only where the dates are equal)

```
Function Spreads()
    Dim data_range As Range
    Dim data As Variant, output_range As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer

    Set data_range = Worksheets("Strategies").Range("A1", "B10")
    data = data_range.Value2

    For i = LBound(data) + 1 To UBound(data)
        For j = LBound(data) + 1 To UBound(data)
            If data(i, 1) = data(j, 1) Then
                If data(i, 2) < data(j, 2) Then
                    ReDim Preserve output_range(x, 3)
                    output_range(x, 1) = data(i, 1)
                    output_range(x, 2) = data(i, 2)
                    output_range(x, 3) = data(j, 2)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    PrintArray output_range, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Strategies").[d1]

End Function

Sub PrintArray(data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

So my output from the above table would be:

```
17/11/2017 2165 2170 
15/12/2017 2165 2170
```

However when I run this nothing happens. Any advise would be appreciated?

Comment: Exactly why you have a `Dictionaty`, loop through the dates, and make column A (your dates) as the `Key`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you need using a `Dictionary` object.

See code below, explanations inisde the code's comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseDict()

Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim Dict        As Object
Dim Key         As Variant
Dim Price       As Variant
Dim i           As Long

With Sheets("Strategies")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Not Dict.exists(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then ' check if current date already exists in the Dictionary
            Dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, .Range("B" & i).Value ' add date as Key
        Else
            ' date already exists in Dictionary, append the Price as the Key Value
            ' add "," so it will be easy to split later to an array
            Dict(.Range("A" & i).Value) = Val(Dict(.Range("A" & i).Value)) & "," & .Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    ' loop through the dictionary, and print values per key (per date)
    ' put in columns C and D , just for comparison reasons
    i = 2 ' start from 2nd row

    For Each Key In Dict.Keys
        Price = Split(Dict(Key), ",") ' split the merged mulitple prices back to array

        ' splitting values from "Merged" string Key to array
        .Range("C" & i).Value = Key
        .Range("D" & i).Resize(1, UBound(Price) + 1).Value = Price
        i = i + 1
    Next Key

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: SO makes the users think the same way - late binding, deliminator, incrementing the value of the dictionary. Still some differences left :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution of the problem. Imagine that your input looks like this:
[image]

Thus, if you start using the dictionary structure in VBA you would be able to achieve something like this:

[image]

The problem with the dictionary structure, is that usually it takes one key and one value. Unless you find a way around it. E.g., you may define a complicated delimiter or you may pass an array as value. In this case, I have defined a complicated delimiter:

```
Public Const DELIM As String = "ITISHELLOWEENTODAY"

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myDict      As Object
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim cnt2        As Long        
    Dim myKey       As String
    Dim myVal       As String
    Dim objK        As Variant
    Dim lngTotal    As Long

    Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")        
    For cnt = 1 To 6
        myKey = Cells(cnt, 1)
        myVal = Cells(cnt, 2)            
        If myDict.Exists(myKey) Then
            myDict(myKey) = Join(Array(myDict(myKey), myVal), DELIM)
        Else
            myDict.Add myKey, myVal
        End If
    Next cnt

    For Each objK In myDict.Keys
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Cells(cnt, 1) = objK            
        Dim myArr As Variant
        myArr = Split(myDict(objK), DELIM)

        For cnt2 = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
            Cells(cnt, 2 + cnt2) = myArr(cnt2)
        Next cnt2
    Next objK

End Sub
```

What it does is pretty much uniting the value of a key like this `1ITISHELLOWEENTODAY11` when it finds a second value, and when it has to print them back to excel, it makes an array, splitted by the deliminiting value (with `Split(myDict(objK), DELIM)`). And printing to the next column.